# Why are the edit/delete/reply links missing in the Comment module?

Tags: 8, comments

I'm using 8.6.0 core's Comment module. I can add comments, but I can't edit or delete them. I also can't reply to anyone else's.

Permissions have been set that all authenticated roles can edit. I'm even an admin and nothing.

I even looked at the `comment.html.twig` template. I don't see any of those links. The only link showing is `{{ permalink }}`. The variables also don't supply any of the links I require.

I looked around and can't find anything related to Drupal 8.

Comment: Are you sure you're logged in as the super admin (user/1)?

Comment: which version of drupal 8, you use ?

Comment: It's version 8.6.0 and yes, I'm using super admin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It ended up being layout builder. Enabled full content and layout builder, cleared cache and it worked.